# Stop JQuery .html() from stripping out tr/td tags

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, stripping

I'm having an issue where the .html() JQuery method is stripping out tr/td tags of my response. Not really sure where to go from here.

Response:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <input value="Blah">
   </td>
</tr>
```

The JQuery doing all the work:

```
$.get(options.addNewLink, function (template) {
    alert(template);
    obj.find('tbody').append(template);
}
```

What gets appended to the tbody is just the "input" tag. The alert function shows that all the data is there and intact, so that's all the tr and td elements. It's just lost in translation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `obj`? Does this only happen in specific browsers? Have you done anything else to diagnose the problem?

Comment: That's weird. Could you show the details of your HTML too?

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Qna6E/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny That's strange how your PoC works. I switched the JQ to my version (v1.6) and it still works.

Comment: @z0nekill so the problem is somewhere else.. can you try to isolate the problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny Hmm.. So I tried doing .append("<tr> + template + "</tr>") and that seemed to give me the data I want in my table. Strange though the tr tags end up surrounding an input tag that's automatically generated by my code prior to the html in my response. Maybe that input tag is messing with the method.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce the problem exactly as asked in the question. Putting that response in a string and appending to a tbody actually worked just fine for me in Chrome 72 with JQuery 1.6 (and also 3.3.1)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
                var template = '<tr><td><input value="Blah"></td><td>col2</td></tr>';
                var obj = $("#myTable");
                alert(template);
                obj.find('tbody').append(template);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="test();">Test</button>&nbsp;
    </body>
</html>
```

With that said, what led me to this question in the first place (and makes me think my response may still be of some small assistance to others finding this) was a very similar problem where trying to extract some tr elements from a response and insert them into an existing table on my page saw all the tr and td being stripped in the manner described by the OP.

My case was to return a response with two sets of rows, one lot in a tbody, and the other in a tfooter, so I wanted to separately copy the child nodes from the tbody and the tfooter into their respective destination nodes in my page's table.

This saw me first parsing the response text into nodes to be able to find the desired subset of nodes inside it to extract and copy to my table (as opposed to just directly appending it in its entirety as the OP does).

Trying to do this, I suddenly found that all the tr,td got stripped when parsing the response.

This was because my response had not wrapped them with a table tag (so the solution was to change the response to surround them with a table tag (instead of a div)) which then allowed the response to be successfully parsed into html without tr,td stripping.

I suspect such stripping is a side effect of how jquery uses the browser's native DOM stuff to parse html strings into actual nodes. When you just append a string full of trs directly into a tbody then it is fine because trs belong in a tbody - they are with their friends and everything is sunshine and roses, but parsing them first means that behind the scenes jquery is instead setting that string into the innerHTML of a div where untabled trs and tds are not in their happy place and browser don't like that.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

                theBodyPart
                    = '<tbody id="resultBody">'
                    + '<tr><td><input value="Hello"></td><td>World</td></tr>'
                    + '<tr><td>abc</td><td>123</td></tr>'
                    + '</tbody>';

                //An outer node is needed for the jquery find() (because find doesnt include the start node in its search)
                badResponse = '<div>' + theBodyPart + '</div>';
                goodResponse = '<table>' + theBodyPart + '</table>';

            function replaceBody(response) {
                var parsedResponse = $( response );
                alert('parsedResponse=' + parsedResponse.html()); //<-- you can see the tr, td stripping of badResponse here
                //parse the html, search for node, use first result
                //(this fails if wrapped in a div instead of a table because the tbody was stripped!)
                var resultBody = parsedResponse.find("#resultBody")[0]; 
                if(resultBody) {
                    $( "#myBody" ).html( $(resultBody).html());
                } else {
                    alert('resultBody not found');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Foo</th><th>Bar</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myBody">
                <tr><td>old1</td><td>old2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="replaceBody(badResponse);">Bad</button>&nbsp;
        <button type="button" onclick="replaceBody(goodResponse);">Good</button><br/>
        <div id="message"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I still don't know why it failed for the OP since they weren't trying to parse and extract from the response before doing the append!